# Mac Os X. Virtual hosts

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

I want to install few virtual hosts on my Mac OS 10.9.4, using apache 2.2.6. I already have one virtual host, it's working correct, but when I added 2nd host it redirects me to 1st.

*/etc/apache2/users/alex.conf*:

```
<Directory "/Users/alex/Sites/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example
   DocumentRoot "/Users/alex/Sites/site1.loc"
   ServerName site1.loc
   ServerAlias site1.loc
   <Directory "/Users/alex/Sites/site1.loc">
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example
   DocumentRoot "/Users/alex/Sites/site2.loc"
   ServerName site2.loc
   ServerAlias site2.loc
   <Directory "/Users/alex/Sites/site2.loc">
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/hotst*:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1 site1.loc
127.0.0.1 site2.loc
```

SITE1.loc works correct, but when I go to site2.loc it redirect to site1.loc. How can I fix this?
Thanks. Sorry for my English

Comment: Run site2 on a different port - e.g. `<VirtualHost *:8080>` then type http://localhost:8080 in your browser

Comment: Or you can do it this way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363925/mac-os-x-mamp-environment-virtual-hosts?rq=1